# Looping through json in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I am creating a weather app in react native using a weather api.

The api gives me the hourly weather from midnight. I would only like to display the weather from the current time and after.

I have tried to loop through the hourly weather using .map and they checked if the information is equal or grater than the current time. I am unable to get this to work or display anything.

Here is my code

```js
 const fetch = require('node-fetch');
              fetch(
                'https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?&q=' +
                  this.state.latitude +
                  ',' +
                  this.state.longitude,
                {
                  method: 'GET',
                  headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  },
                },
              )
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(responseJson => {
                  console.log(responseJson);
                  this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson,
                  });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                  console.error(error);
                });
            },
          );
          
   renderView() {
    this.state.dataSource.forecast.forecastday[0].hour.map(item =>
      this.state.dataSource.location.localtime_epoch >= item.time_epoch ? (
        <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              flexDilocaltime_eprection: 'row',
              textAlign: 'center',
            }}>
            <View>
              <Text>{item.time.split(' ')[1]}</Text>
              <Image
                source={{url: 'https:' + item.condition.icon}}
                style={{
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  paddingBottom: 10,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                }}
              />
              <Text>{item.temp_c + '℃'}</Text>
            </View>
            ): <Text>{item.time_epoch}</Text> );
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      ) : (
        <Text>Not Found!</Text>
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is the json

```js
{
    "location": {
        "name": "New York",
        "region": "New York",
        "country": "United States of America",
        "lat": 40.71,
        "lon": -74.01,
        "tz_id": "America/New_York",
        "localtime_epoch": 1623928876,
        "localtime": "2021-06-17 7:21"
    },
    "current": {
        "last_updated_epoch": 1623928500,
        "last_updated": "2021-06-17 07:15",
        "temp_c": 15.6,
        "temp_f": 60.1,
        "is_day": 1,
        "condition": {
            "text": "Sunny",
            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png",
            "code": 1000
        },
        "wind_mph": 4.3,
        "wind_kph": 6.8,
        "wind_degree": 310,
        "wind_dir": "NW",
        "pressure_mb": 1016.0,
        "pressure_in": 30.5,
        "precip_mm": 0.0,
        "precip_in": 0.0,
        "humidity": 46,
        "cloud": 0,
        "feelslike_c": 15.6,
        "feelslike_f": 60.1,
        "vis_km": 10.0,
        "vis_miles": 6.0,
        "uv": 1.0,
        "gust_mph": 8.7,
        "gust_kph": 14.0
    },
    "forecast": {
        "forecastday": [
            {
                "date": "2021-06-17",
                "date_epoch": 1623888000,
                "day": {
                    "maxtemp_c": 27.0,
                    "maxtemp_f": 80.6,
                    "mintemp_c": 15.9,
                    "mintemp_f": 60.6,
                    "maxwind_mph": 8.3,
                    "maxwind_kph": 13.3,
                    "totalprecip_mm": 0.0,
                    "totalprecip_in": 0.0,
                    "avgvis_km": 10.0,
                    "avgvis_miles": 6.0,
                    "avghumidity": 35.0,
                    "daily_will_it_rain": 0,
                    "daily_chance_of_rain": "0",
                    "daily_will_it_snow": 0,
                    "daily_chance_of_snow": "0",
                    "condition": {
                        "text": "Partly cloudy",
                        "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png",
                        "code": 1003
                    },
                    "uv": 7.0
                },
                "astro": {
                    "sunrise": "05:25 AM",
                    "sunset": "08:30 PM",
                    "moonrise": "12:16 PM",
                    "moonset": "01:02 AM",
                    "moon_phase": "Waxing Gibbous",
                    "moon_illumination": "55"
                },
                "hour": [
                    {
                        "time_epoch": 1623902400,
                        "time": "2021-06-17 00:00",
                        "temp_c": 17.8,
                        "temp_f": 64.0,
                        "is_day": 0,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        },
                        "wind_mph": 9.6,
                        "wind_kph": 15.5,
                        "wind_degree": 326,
                        "wind_dir": "NNW",
                        "pressure_mb": 1014.0,
                        "pressure_in": 30.4,
                        "precip_mm": 0.0,
                        "precip_in": 0.0,
                        "humidity": 43,
                        "cloud": 12,
                        "feelslike_c": 17.8,
                        "feelslike_f": 64.0,
                        "windchill_c": 17.8,
                        "windchill_f": 64.0,
                        "heatindex_c": 17.8,
                        "heatindex_f": 64.0,
                        "dewpoint_c": 5.1,
                        "dewpoint_f": 41.2,
                        "will_it_rain": 0,
                        "chance_of_rain": "0",
                        "will_it_snow": 0,
                        "chance_of_snow": "0",
                        "vis_km": 10.0,
                        "vis_miles": 6.0,
                        "gust_mph": 13.0,
                        "gust_kph": 20.9,
                        "uv": 1.0
                    },
                    {
                        "time_epoch": 1623906000,
                        "time": "2021-06-17 01:00",
                        "temp_c": 16.9,
                        "temp_f": 62.4,
                        "is_day": 0,
                        "condition": {
                            "text": "Partly cloudy",
                            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/116.png",
                            "code": 1003
                        },
                        "wind_mph": 8.7,
                        "wind_kph": 14.0,
                        "wind_degree": 321,
                        "wind_dir": "NW",
                        "pressure_mb": 1014.0,
                        "pressure_in": 30.4,
                        "precip_mm": 0.0,
                        "precip_in": 0.0,
                        "humidity": 44,
                        "cloud": 21,
                        "feelslike_c": 16.9,
                        "feelslike_f": 62.4,
                        "windchill_c": 16.9,
                        "windchill_f": 62.4,
                        "heatindex_c": 16.9,
                        "heatindex_f": 62.4,
                        "dewpoint_c": 4.6,
                        "dewpoint_f": 40.3,
                        "will_it_rain": 0,
                        "chance_of_rain": "0",
                        "will_it_snow": 0,
                        "chance_of_snow": "0",
                        "vis_km": 10.0,
                        "vis_miles": 6.0,
                        "gust_mph": 11.6,
                        "gust_kph": 18.7,
                        "uv": 1.0
                    },
            }
```

Comment: Try make a minimally reproducible example using codesandbox to properly demonstrate how it doesn't display anything.

Comment: If you aren't using any react-native specific functions in your problem, I don't see any problem replicating the demo in react web. Unless your problem is with a react-native library and the code only fails in react-native, then you can also improve your question by providing more accurate information. This should help you debug regardless.

Comment: I'm actually using react-native-geolocation-service

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-feather-bu45f?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is in the renderView function.** You have **not returned** anything from the function. All you need to do is:

```
renderView(){
return(//whatever you are rendering)
}
```

I made this change in the CodeSandbox provided by you and it works fine now.

Edited:

The image isn't visible because, the source of the image should be **"uri" and not "url"**.

```
source={{uri: 'https:' + item.condition.icon}}
```

Comment: can't find the change

Comment: The source of the image should be uri and not url, updated my solution.